# Dynamically created XML from PHP to Actionscript 3

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to dynamically create an XML file using php like this:

```
  header ("content-type: text/xml");

  // create doctype
  $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

  // create root element
  $root = $dom->createElement("tracklist");
  $dom->appendChild($root);
  $dom->formatOutput=true;

  // create child element
  foreach ($commonPlaylist as $value) {

     $trackArray = getTrackForID($value['ID']);

     $item = $dom->createElement("track");
     $root->appendChild($item);

     foreach ( $trackArray as $key => $value) {
      $attr = $dom->createAttribute($key);
      $item->appendChild($attr);

          $attrValue = $dom->createTextNode($value);
      $attr->appendChild($attrValue);
     }

  }

 echo $dom->saveXML();
```

The output of the file is normal working xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <tracklist>
        <track ID="4" title="Track01" artist="Artist01" url="" length="" coverURL=""/>
        <track ID="1" title="Track02" artist="Artist02" url="" length="" coverURL=""/>
        <track ID="8" title="Track03" artist="Artist03" url="" length="" coverURL=""/>
   </tracklist>
```

However if I want to get this data into as3 with the following code:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("getPlaylist.php"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    var myXml:XML= new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXml);  // The variable is being traced.
```

}

I don't get any output at all. If I read the file as a String I get the whole PHP code. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Regards,
Matteo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I read the file as a String I get the whole PHP code

It sounds like it's not being executed server-side. Are you hosting it on a server with PHP installed?

Comment: I could so punch myself in the face right now. I am testing this on a local server. I always kept checking the file in my browser like this http://localhost:8888/Project/getCommonPlaylist.php while I loaded it into the flash file without the localhost:8888 that's why PHP didn't work. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Jap was correct I just had to wait a few minutes until I could accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the variable name

- You're tracing myXML  & the XML variable name is myXml

Comment: I typed that while writing my question. It's not the problem inside my code.

Comment: Alright, corrected the variable name.

How about you trace the output from the URL request before creating a new XML object? Does that show the output?


correct me if I am wrong.

I guess it won't , since the URL should be specify the scheme *http://* 'localhost/getPlaylist.php'

Answer (score 0):

Is `processXML()` actually triggered? Try modifying it like in the following code and see if you get the "Hi!" part traced.

```
function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    trace('Hi!');
    var myXml:XML= new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML);
}
```

BTW, using a Flash debugger might be much more useful from trying to guess what went wrong :) Since the one shipped with Flash Professional sucks big time I can only recommend [DeMonster debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) which saved me a lot of time while working on Flash projects. It also wouldn't hurt to have an HTTP traffic analysis tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).